# How to redirect to a page if you do not have permission?

Tags: liferay

I added a `portal-ext.properties` the following:

```
layout.friendly.url.page.not.found = /html/portal/404.html
```

Now when I access a nonexistent page, I'am automatically redirected to `404.html`. I also want this to happen when I go to page I'm not permitted to access. I should be redirected to another page, for example `/html/portal/page-without-permission.html`.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct property which you can change like that. You will have to handle it in the code

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is something that can be achieved only via an ext plugin.
When a user is not permitted to access some page,the page is actually not visible to the the user.This behaviour is handled in Util and service classes within portal-impl,and hence need to be handled by an ext.
As the page is invisible,hence for the provided page name there is no valid layout id for the page(as per the permission),and hence directs user to 404 page.